# Powershell remove a file from multiple users' startup folders

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to write a script to remove a batch file from the startup folder of every computer on the network. On some computers the file is located in the all users startup folder, so that part is easy. However, I can't figure out how I can search all of the user account startup folders on each computer to make sure I remove every instance of the file. I tried the following:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {remove-item -Path 'c:\Users\%username%\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\Start Menu\programs\startup\logon.bat' }
```

I assumed that Powershell would see %usertname% as a variable and just look through all of the usernames, but I was wrong. Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: 2 points here. 1. environment variables in PowerShell use. `$env:username`. 2. They only have context of the running user. You would have to search all folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to replace the `%username%` with a `*` since it accepts wildcards. That would help check every folder.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {remove-item -Path 'c:\Users\*\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\Start Menu\programs\startup\logon.bat' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

Environment variables in PowerShell use the convention `$env:variablename`. `Get-ChildItem env:` will show you all variables much in the same way as in the System Properties dialog.

You need to use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` as it will fail if you dont have permissions to search the folders. You could make it more resilient with things like `Test-Path` but this should be simple enough.

Using `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` with `Remove-Item` wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
Foreach ($Computer in $computers){invoke-command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
$Directories = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | ? {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}
ForEach($Directory in $Directories){
$File=($Directory.FullName) + "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\Start Menu\programs\startup\logon.bat"
If(Test-path $File){
remove-item $File}}}}
```